# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

```
public Player(string name, List<Card> cards)
{
   this.name = name;
   try
   {
      this.stack.insertCards(cards);//Here is the NullReferenceExeption
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {                
      throw e;
   }
}

public void insertCards(List<Card> cards)
{
   stack.AddRange(cards);
}

public List<Card> GetSevenCards() //the Player gets the Cards from this function
{
   List<Card> list = new List<Card>();
   int ran;
   Random r = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
   {
      ran = r.Next(0, stack.Count()-1);
      list.Add(stack[ran]);
      stack.RemoveAt(ran);
   }
   return list;
}
```

the stack gets a cardlist of 7 Cards

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem; otherwise we're just guessing. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
this.stack.insertCards(GetSevenCards());
```

and create new instance of stack.

Because cards are null. Fill them with function first.

Can't say more things, because you didn't give more information about definitions. There should be more codes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to make sure that `stack` is instantiated inside the class:

```
private YourStackImplementation stack = new YourStackImplementation();
```

Comment: -1. this isn't a real "stack" as the .net stack has no .insertCards method like he is defining. He has written his own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see stack ever being initialized. You have to initialize stack before you can call any non-static methods on it.

```
var stack = new Stack();
```

Comment: thanks ... sorry for the stupid question